# Fourth power and least common multiple (urgent)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been given a mathematics test with the question* (we are allowed to use online resources):

Find all **positive answers** for the following expression

$$ x - y^4 = \def\LCM{{\rm lcm}}\LCM(x, y)$$

No matter what I set $x$ and $y$ as, there always seems to be a difference between $x - y^4$ and $\LCM(x, y)$.

Can anyone help with this problem?

If you need some more clarification, here is an example:

$x = 32, y = 2$, so $y^4 = 16$
$$ x - y^4 = 32 - 16 = 16 \neq 32 = \LCM(32, 2) = \LCM(x, y) $$

In this example (and all others that I've tried), $x - y^4$ doesn't equal $\LCM(x, y)$.

**Question 3 of 12, if you were wondering...*

Comment: Have a gook look at the edition of your question. You are lucky that was done. It is beyond doubt that "urge" is disliked here. Learn from this when it comes to asking questions.

Comment: If your instructor says an answer is urgent, then it means the answer is either in your textbook or in your notes. It can also mean that your instructor is an incompetent narcissist, but that wouldn't be my first guess in mathematics (if this was a screenwriting class, then I would go to the latter conclusion).

Comment: @BobHapp, we were given notes, but frankly, the notes provided do not give enough context to even be worth any use. Also, we haven't been given a textbook for this purpose. Finally, I said it was urgent, not my instructor.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Note, that if $x,y > 0$. Then $x-y^4 < x$, but ${\rm lcm}(x,y) \ge x$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $y^4=x-{\rm lcm}(x,y).$ Here, since ${\rm lcm}(x,y)\ge x$, the RHS is non-positive. Namely, $y^4=x-{\rm lcm}(x,y)\le 0$, which leads $y=0$.

Comment: So you are saying that _y = 0_ and _x = any value_? Is that right?

Comment: @Ashjayeen: No. I'm saying that if we suppose that there exist such **positive** integers, then we have $y=0$, which is a contradiction. Hence, there exist no such positive integers.

Comment: So, there are no possible answers?

Comment: @Ashjayeen: No, there exist no such **positive** integers.

Comment: So you are saying that there are no positive integers. So can I have any valid answers then?

Comment: @Ashjayeen: What do you mean? I've already proved that there are no such positive integers. Isn't this enough?